# Django Rest Framework: insert list using ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The online documentation is not very clear. The default POST method of `ModelViewSet` is supposed to allow you to insert a list of your models, but in reality it only allows single model insertion. For code example, please refer to the one stated in the https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/, how could someone POST a list of users?

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: What do you mean, "is supposed to"? Where did you get that from?

Comment: it's called View**Set** as opposed to View

Comment: I don't see the relevance. It's called that because it is a set of views, that deals with lists, details, creating and updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear about what the creation does.

Quoting https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset:

> The ModelViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.
>   The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy().

So referring to the [GenericAPIView documentation at creation mixing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin):

> Provides a .create(request, *args, **kwargs) method, that implements creating and saving a new model instance.

So if you want to create a batch of items, you'll have to override the `create` method and write the [multiple instance creation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Since it's called ModelView**Set**, I was assuming it handled list creation by default. BTW with ModelViewSet, how do you call `create()`, I'm pretty new to the framework.

Comment: You should take some time and run the full tutorial once to grab the concepts and ideas around DRF.

Answer (score 0):

because you can use serializer_class first and than queryset, first we need to import User and than apply serializer class to apply insertion again ad again
use this

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```